# ZF2 hostname match assemble url and 404

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-framework-mvc

I have the following code to match a route with a hostname;

```
'router' => [
    'router_class' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\TranslatorAwareTreeRouteStack',
    'routes' => [
        'website' => [
            'type' => 'hostname',
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'options' => [
                'route' => ':locale.domain.:tld',
                'constraints' => [
                    'language' => '(nl|en)',
                    'tld' => '(dev|org)',
                ],
            ],
        ]
    ],
],
```

And some routes to match the uri.

So in dev I can have routes like `en.domain.dev` and `nl.domain.dev`. The translation of the route also works like a charm but then my 'issues' occur

**1. Assemble url**

For every url I now need the `locale` and `tld` variable. To do this I do `<?= $this->url('website/languages', [], true); ?>`, but that makes it a mess. Because I only want to use the TLD and locale of the current route.

So I came with the solution to extend the URL view helper. And set the `locale` and `tld` param when it was not set with the route match. This worked for 1 'minor' problem, see 2. But was wondering if there was a beter solution for this.

**2. 404 paga**

In 1 I use the current route match to get the `locale`/`tld` to assemble url's this all works, except for the 404 page. Because than there is no route match, obviously.

I started digging arround and when I found the router (from the `service locator`). I tried to get the route for `website` it only returned `Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Part`. 
The `protected $route` was the  `Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Hostname` which is not accessible. So no luck that way.

The only way I got the Hostname route was by constructing it my self, which I don't really want to do.

So the question is how do you easily reuse the hostname params, and get the hostname params on a 404 page?

*I know that for example test.domain.test will not match the hostname and will provide a broken Hostname, but that is a matter of Nginx. So Nginx will make sure the hostname are always correct*

Comment: Not sure if I understood you correctly. You can write a view helper in which you inject the params. And you can use the helper in your 404 view script.

Comment: I could but the params are based on the hostname, and in scenario 1 I need them everytime in my url viewhelper. In de second scenario the problem is there is no route match

Answer (score 1):

Well I continued searching and thinking and came with a 'solution'.

To tackle **2.** I created a listener that listens on the `MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR`.

Code;

```
// use are above the class declaration
use Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\TranslatorAwareTreeRouteStack;
use Zend\EventManager\AbstractListenerAggregate;
use Zend\EventManager\EventManagerInterface;
use Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request;
use Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\RouteMatch;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

public function onDispatchError(MvcEvent $event)
{
    if (is_null($event->getRouteMatch())) {
        $router = $event->getRouter();
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        if ($router instanceof TranslatorAwareTreeRouteStack && $request instanceof Request) {
            $match = $router->getRoute('website')->match($request, strlen($request->getUri()->getPath()), array(
                'translator' => $router->getTranslator(),
            ));
            if ($match instanceof RouteMatch) {
                $match->setMatchedRouteName('website');
                $event->setRouteMatch($match);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

What it does;

1. check if there is a route match, if not it is a 404
2. check the `$router` is `TranslatorAwareTreeRouteStack` and the `$request` is a `HttpRequest`
3. get the route for `website` (this is the route for the hostname`
4. then it matches it (the trick is that offset is set so only the hostname is checked)
5. sets the route matched name (is empty if not set which will lead to issues)
6. then the routematch is injected in the event

To tackle **1.** I now had always access to a `route match` so I could do some own magic. I extended the `url viewhelper`.

```
public function __invoke(
    $name = null,
    $params = array(),
    $options = array(),
    $reuseMatchedParams = false
) {
    if ($this->routeMatch instanceof RouteMatch) {
        foreach(['locale', 'tld'] as $key) {
            if (!array_key_exists($key, $params)) {
                $params[$key] = $this->routeMatch->getParam($key);
            }
        }
    }

    // This is needed for the magic that can happen when `reuseMatchedParams` is used at the third position
    if (is_bool($options)) {
        $reuseMatchedParams = $options;
        $options = array();
    }

    return parent::__invoke(
        $name,
        $params,
        $options,
        $reuseMatchedParams
    );
}
```

Not the most elegant method but it works for now